# Erro com assincronismo no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-eventos

Galera, tem uma lista (em uma pagina web) que quando faço scroll ela carrega novos elementos, Suponha que seja a lista [joão, paulo, pedro], ao dar scroll como dito anteriormente ela vai carregar hipoteticamente os elementos [joão, paulo, pedro, fernando, maria]. Estou criando um código que vai carregar todos os elementos para joga-los dentro de uma lista. A dinâmica é: ao rolar a janela, a pagina faz um request dos novos elementos da lista ao servidor. O problema é: acredito que a variável current está recebendo o valor antes dos elementos serem carregados na DOM, logo, o atual é sempre igual ao anterior. Esse loop iria fazer scroll até que todos os elementos da lista tenham sido carregados em tela.

Pensei em setar um setTimeOut depois que o scroll é feito, mas isso iria deixar o script muito lento.

```
function dissect(node){
    //essa função só serve para navegar em um elemento da DOM
    node = node.firstChild;
    node = node.childNodes;
    node = node[0];
    node = node.firstChild;
    node = node.lastChild;
    return(node.getAttribute('href'));
}

function loadWindow(){
    //recovering last child
    var seguidores = document.querySelector('div.PZuss');
    var last = dissect(seguidores.lastChild);
    var current = undefined;

    //recovering window
    var window = document.querySelector('div.isgrP');
    console.log(window);

    while(current != last){
        last = dissect(seguidores.lastChild);
        window.scroll(0, 1000);
        current = dissect(seguidores.lastChild);

    }
}

loadWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você acredita que o problema ocasionado é por causa de um elemento não ter carregado ainda, você pode verificar se o elemento existe, com o seguinte JS

```
if (document.getElementById('id_elemento')){
 //Agora você pode setar valor na variável current
    console.log('existe');
}
```

Comment: Não tem como, essa lista contem somente classes. fiz uma edição na pergunta e adicionei o código dela.

Comment: document.querySelector não funcionaria? Ou pegar pelo path através do console?

Answer (score 0):

como está o seu método que faz a busca?
Se o seu problema é realmente dele fazer a busca e não esperar, você pode usar **async/await** ou usar um **then** na sua promise